# Rails - Could not find i18n-0.9.5 in any of the sources

Tags: mysql, ruby, bundler, globalize, rails-generate

I'm working on a Ruby website using MySQL and I was working on internationalization using Globalize.

However, when I run `rails g migration create_translation_for_articles`
The terminal displays the following:

```
Could not find i18n-0.9.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I added `gem 'i18n', '~> 0.9.5'` to Gemfile and ran `bundle install` but still no change.

How can I fix this issue?

**UPDATE**: the message appears when I run any `rails g` command

Note: Adding the gem or not makes no difference. Installing `i18n` using `gem install` gives the same result too.

The content of my Gemfile is :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.4'
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.3'


gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.1'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.3'

gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'dotenv', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'

gem 'countries', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.3'
gem 'flag-icons-rails'

gem 'country_select'

gem 'activeadmin_froala_editor', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.3'

gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 5.1'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.5'
gem 'globalize', '~> 5.1'
gem 'activeadmin-globalize', '~> 1.0.0.pre'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: what is the `source` on top of your Gemfile? Does it work if you try to install it localy via `gem install i18n -v 0.9.5`?

Comment: No. It doesn't work even with ```geme install i18n -v 0.9.5```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you update your question to show the content of your `Gemfile`?

In the meantime, here are 2 suggestions you could try:

- If you manage your gems using gemset, you could remove the gemset for that particular project using `rvm gemset empty gemsetname` or the rbenv equivalent if you use rbenv. Then run bundle install again.
- I've seen this happen a lot because of spring. If you happen to have the spring gem in your `Gemfile`, run `bin/spring stop`.

Comment: I updated my question with the content of my Gemfile

Comment: Okay, seen, run `bin/spring stop` from your terminal and try again. Does that help?

Comment: Nope, didn't help me.
Aha, fixed for me by `rm Gemfile.lock;`!